# No module named statistics.distributions

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, sympy

I was trying to use Sympy stats library when i encountered this problem:

```
>>> from sympy.statistics.distributions import Sample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named statistics.distributions
```

The problem is not only in my system as the same happened in their SymPy Live Shell. You can see it [here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/statistics.html#sample). Can you please help me fix this.

Comment: The live shell runs version `1.0`, the code you're trying to run is from version `0.70`

Comment: I see. Upon further reading i saw that `statistics` has been deprecated. But I cannot find any alternative to find the mean of a list using Sympy.

Comment: I guess thats a different question then. Maybe you should post the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sympy.statistics` has been removed in favor of `sympy.stats`. Here is the documentation: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html.

For producing the mean of a list of numbers, you can use `DiscreteUniform`:

```
In [8]: from sympy.stats import DiscreteUniform, E

In [9]: X = DiscreteUniform("X", [1, 2, 3])

In [10]: E(X)
Out[10]: 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it works. I hope something like `Sample` is brought back as it was very useful.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that for floating point statistics, you are better off using a numeric library like `scipy.stats`.